# Producing PDF/A compliant illustrations

Tags: pdftex, transparency, inkscape, pdf-a

I'm trying to produce a PDF/A-compliant thesis which containts several illustrations made with inkscape and exported to pdf.

When I check the output with veraPDF, it keeps complaining that my images contain transparency, which is forbidden by the standard. This happens even if I did not actually use transparent colors in inkscape; at least as far as my understanding of "transparency goes". I only used flat colors with 100% alpha.

1. Is there a way to export images to pdf with inkscape while forcibly removing any transparency?
2. If not, is there a (possibly simple) way to remove this transparency afterwards? Or, even better, while including the illustration with \includegraphics?

Comment: Add a MWE with one image.

Comment: Does your main tex file insert `pdfx` package and do you have a xmpdata file in your prject folder? I think the drawings themselves exported from Inkscape (my version is 1.1) are not compliant with PDF/A but it seems the package `pdfx` converts them to the correct form because the end pdf seems to be OK, at least for me.

Comment: Would adding a white background rectangle in InkScape help?

Comment: @Celdor pdfx doesn't convert images.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I understand. PDFs exported from Inkscape (my ver. 1.1) are not PDF/A compliant. `veraPDF` issues a report with a number of errors. One of them is related to transparency, similarly to what OP has mentioned but there are other issues. The same exact PDFs included in a tex file, which loads `pdfx,` seem not to cause problems; the resulted PDF is compliant with PDF/A. I thought `pdfx` would process them somehow but I was wrong.